# Can't open external link in dropbox hosted website

Tags: javascript, html

I have a single html page hosted in my Public Dropbox folder. 
The page loads and all works well except when I try to navigate a new page to an external website.

The url is supposed to go to "www.paypal.me/cloud9cincy/"

But when the page loads, it goes to "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/33811101/www.paypal.me/cloud9cincy/"

I cannot figure out how to make this work.

```
function paypal(){
    var test = $('#paypal').attr("href");
    window.open(test, '_blank');
}

<button id="paypal" onClick="paypal();">Donate to Cloud9:Cincy</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you have something like this:

```
<a id="paypal" href="www.paypal.me/cloud9cincy/">paypal link</a>
```

That is being interpreted as a relative URL. You should instead specify it absolutely like:

```
<a id="paypal" href="https://www.paypal.me/cloud9cincy/">paypal link</a>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that did the job.